# How to authenticate with APIKey and URL on .NET SDK Watson

Tags: c#, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

How to authenticate with APIKey and URL (https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-understanding/api) on .NET SDK Watson (https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk).

The SDK example have `SpeechToTextService(username, password);` But now the Watson Credential only have APIKey and URL.

```
    const string SERVICE_NAME = "speech_to_text";
    const string URL = "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api";

    public SpeechToTextService() : base(SERVICE_NAME) { }

    public SpeechToTextService(string userName, string password) : base(SERVICE_NAME, URL)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userName));

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(password));

        this.SetCredential(userName, password);
    }

    public SpeechToTextService(TokenOptions options) : base(SERVICE_NAME, URL)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.IamApiKey) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.IamAccessToken))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options.IamAccessToken) + ", " + nameof(options.IamApiKey));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.ServiceUrl))
        {
            this.Endpoint = options.ServiceUrl;
        }
        else
        {
            options.ServiceUrl = this.Endpoint;
        }

        _tokenManager = new TokenManager(options);
    }

    public SpeechToTextService(IClient httpClient) : base(SERVICE_NAME, URL)
    {
        if (httpClient == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpClient));

        this.Client = httpClient;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take at look at the IAM key examples in the [README](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk#supplying-the-iam-api-key). You can supply the key and URL like this,

```
IamApiKey = "<iam-apikey>",
ServiceUrl = "<service-endpoint>"
```

Also look at the information about using a `ibm-credentials.env` file.